# C# database file directory

Tags: c#, database, winforms, ms-access, directory

I'm using the windows forms aplication with an ms access database. And i would like to know if there is a way to show the directory of the database file (to save data in it)excpet like this:

string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=save.mdb";

```
        OleDbConnection empConnection = new OleDbConnection(conString);


        string insertStatement = "INSERT INTO zivila "
                             + "([naziv],[kalorij],[beljakovin],[oh],[mascob]) "
                             + "VALUES (@naziv,@kalorij,@beljakovin,@oh,@mascob)";
```

or this:

- "Data Source=D:\Simonova aktovka na namizju\matura\test5\save.mdb";

couse if i use the first one the aplication undos the changes i've made when i close it(the aplication)
the second one makes me have to change the path everytime i bring the aplication to another computer(cous the direktory is different of coars)
So... is there another way?

Comment: Could you make your question a bit clearer?

Comment: Do you wish to dynamically obtain the path to the mdb?

Comment: I don't know what u mean, but i would like to not need to change the databases path all the time a move it, and i don't wan't the aplication to undo the changes i'v made in the database.

Comment: How do you imagine this happening? Do you want to set a registry key when installing? Store to a file? Scan folders? Ask the user?

Comment: I just wan't to store the new data in the database(ms access file). and i wan't it(the new inserted data) to be useable with no restart of the aplication needed

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Data Source=|DataDirectory|\save.mdb
```

Comment: I think you should add some code to your question showing how you use this.

Comment: @Simon: How do you say it deletes the stuff. Are you sure you are checking the save.mdb inside your solution folder where your project resides?

Comment: yes. But i tried it again and it's like this. If i use it like this:
Data Source=save.mdb"; It saves the data in it. And until i close the aplication the data is useable.But if i restart the aplication the new data is not in the database anymore.
if i write the whole path. The data i record isn't useable . I have to restart the aplication, and the data i inserted before is useable.